# I am trying to turn a string into an integer in python, but it won't let me

Tags: python, string

```
#itemsInExistence defined here:
itemName = input("What do you want the new item to be called? ")
itemStats = int(input("What is its stat? "))
itemAmount = int(input("How many of it are there? "))
itemRank = int(input("What is its base rank? "))
itemStats = int(itemStats)
itemAmount = int(itemAmount)
itemRank = int(itemRank)
for i in range(itemAmount):
  itemsInExistence.append([itemName, itemStats, itemAmount, itemRank])

#an Item is randomly chosen from itemsInExistence here:
gains = random.randint(1, 5)
if gains == 2:
  gained_weapon = random.choice(itemsInExistence)
  print("You gained the item", gained_weapon)
  itemMatrix.append(gained_weapon)
  for i, item in enumerate(itemsInExistence):
    if gained_weapon == itemsInExistence[i]:
      del itemsInExistence[i]
      break

#Here I am attempting to add what was previously known as itemStats of the 2 items together:
print("Choose two items to craft with by selecting the number to the left of it. Remember 
their 3rd numbers have to match!")
item1 = input("Item 1: ")
item2 = input("Item 2: ")
item1 = int(item1)
item2 = int(item2)
--itemMatrix[item1][-5] = int(itemMatrix[item1][-5])--
#The error occurs on the line above
itemMatrix[item1][-5] += int(itemMatrix[item2][-5])
```

itemMatrix[item1] looks like ['Name', 1, 3, 1]

itemMatrix[item1][-5] looks like 3

No matter what I try, it keeps saying that 'str does not support that item assignment/operation'. Any ways to get around this?

Thanks for you time!

Comment: please copy the full error message and highlight the concerned line of code.

Comment: I will try. I don't know how to highlight yet.

Comment: oh nvm it's fine this way I hadn't seen.
Why the -5 though ? that's weird.

Comment: i edited it to show why it was -5.

Comment: Why are you using -5 as an index?

Comment: What is the `--` before that line supposed to be doing?

Comment: that was to highlight the problematic code for Loic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We expect a minimal example and a full error message (including the trace-back to show provenance and location).  Your posted code requires a lot of hand input that is unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not be a perfect solution, but it will surely help you a lot !

Use dictionaries to manage your game data, it will make things much easier :

```
items_in_existence = []

item = {}
item['name'] = input("What do you want the new item to be called? ")
item['stats'] = int(input("What is its stat? "))
item['rank'] = int(input("What is its base rank? "))
item['amount'] = int(input("How many of it are there? "))

for i in range(item['amount'])):
    items_in_existence.append(item)
```

this way instead of using numbers to access the properties of an item, you can directly use the property name :

```
for item in items_in_existence:
    print(item['name'], item['rank'])
```

Comment: It will be awhile before I can finish implementing this, but I will get back to you when I am finished.

Comment: alright, let me know if you have any issue. I bet it will make everything much easier.

Comment: Sorry, I am just now starting. Lit + Comp. is a painfully long class.

Comment: Is there some way to make the dictionary carry over when assigned to a different list? When the item in itemsInExistence is transfered to gained_weapon and then into itemMatrix, it loses its separate values, becoming one string. That is the problem I need fixing, although this really helped as well.

Comment: hm, I don't understand what you need, please could you create a new question on stack overflow ?

Comment: I think you need : ```itemMatrix = {'item1': itemsInExistence[item1], 'item2': itemsInExistence[item2]}```

Comment: That won't work, itemMatrix is supposed to be the player's inventory, but it was named before I determined that, and I don't feel like going through and renaming them all.